# Can an APPX Windows Store Package contain multiple "applications"?

Tags: microsoft-metro, package, windows-store, appx, appxmanifest

I'm trying to understand the appxmanifest file for APPX packages better. I noticed it has an `<Applications>` tag followed by a single `<Application>` tag for every example I've seen. It would appear though that multiple "applications" can be included in the Manifest. What would this actually even mean though? Is this actually possible or was Microsoft just thinking about forward compatibility when designing the AppxManifest schema?

Answer (score 2):

The manifest does define this as a possibility, and with hand editing, it is possible to do this.

However, you won't pass store certification for this I believe.

Answer (score -2):

.appxbundle package is the likely solution to your question.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/bg182885.aspx#two

Comment: Please add a summary of the solution as well the link - link only answers may break in the future and are not considered good practice

Comment: the link is broken now