# Running different version of app in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

Can I run different versions of applications of my application run on the same machine?

eg: myapp 1.0, myapp 1.1, my app 1.2?   *(These versions need to have 1 tile as their point of entry)*

Comment: I guess this is what I was kinda looking for. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604663/can-an-appx-windows-store-package-contain-multiple-applications

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
Just go to Package.appxmanifest -> Packaging and change the "Package Name" manually.